# using a light switch for electric baseboard heater

Tags: electrical

Can i use a light switch to turn on and off a cadet 36” 120 volt baseboard heater. So it would either be full on or full off. It is wired now for a line voltage thermostat but in this time of the virus i’d rather use what i have on hand, which is light switches.

Comment: Umm...why do you want to replace the thermostat?  Did it fail?

Comment: How many watts does the heater pull?

Answer (score 2):

As long as the amperage of the heater is 15A or less, then a normal light switch should be fine.  If the amperage is higher, you can get 20A switches that are "heavy duty".

Comment: The nameplate probably shows watts, not amps. 15 A is the same as 1800 W. 20 A is the same as 2400 W

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg A little more complicated than that because of derating for continuous usage. Best is to check what breaker is installed and make sure the switch is rated the same or higher.

Answer (score 1):

The switch must be rated for the load, watts divided by volts equals amps. You should check the rating of the heater, but most baseboard heaters are rated for about 250W per foot, so it should be around 750W. 500W per foot would just be scary hot, not sleeping in any room or house with that heater!

The NEC considers fixed electric space heating equipment as "continuous" (3+ hours at full power), and requires *breakers* and *wire* to be 125% of such loads. If it is on a 15A breaker the load should already be less than 12A, so a 15A (or 20A) switch should be fine.

If on a 20A breaker the easy route is to use a 20A switch, but you still may only need a 15A. A general purpose snap switch is required to be rated for the load, this is not the same as the breaker rating. You could have two bedrooms with 36" 750 watt heaters on separate thermostats served the same circuit. 1500 watts at 120V is 12.5A, so the minimum sized breaker and wire would be 15.62A, so you would need a 20A breaker and wire, but the two thermostats or switches would only need to be rated for the loads served.